# How can I remove the hyphen at the end?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Heres my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

s = raw_input()
n = input()
x = (s + " ") * n
def remove(x):
  return x.replace(" ","-")

print remove(x)
```

Basically its like this

```
s = abc
n = 2
```

I want to print abc-abc
but I end up getting abc-abc-

don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input()
x = (s + " ") * n
```

Assuming you enter 'abc' and '2', the string becomes 'abc abc ' (**Note the space at the end)**. When you replace  with `-`, it replaces the trailing space with a `-`. A very quick solution would be to use

`x.replace(" ", "-", n-1)`

The third parameter is the `count`, so it will replace all but the trailing space.

Comment: This worked but there was a white space at the end of that sentence. The software that corrects my code doesn't want that whitespace there

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job

```
'-'.join([s]*n)
```

for your data it will be `abc-abc`

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

s = raw_input()
n = input()
x = (s + " ") * (n-1)
x += s
def remove(x):
  return x.replace(" ","-")

print remove(x)
```

So the last 's' would not add any space to x and therefor there is no space at the end to turn into a hyphen.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me but I was wondering, what exactly does x += s do?

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply but what does the += do?

Comment: It is the same as x = x +s